# jQuery UI dialog title task

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How would you override `jQuery UI`'s default functionality so that whenever I set a new title for a dialog - it adds `xxx` in front of it? So `$("#any_dialog_id").dialog("option", "title", "yyy")` would set title to `xxxyyy`.

```
$().ready(function(){

    $("#dialog").dialog();

    $(".ui-dialog-title").before("xxx");

    // I add the line //
    $("#any_dialog_id").dialog("option", "title", "yyy"); 

});
```

But he show `yyyxxx` not `xxxyyy`

What I have to do, to make it work??

Thanks...

Comment: `whenever I set a new title`... why can't you concatenate to new title text?

Comment: I have to write exactly this line $("#any_dialog_id").dialog("option", "title", "yyy");

Comment: And outcome has to be "xxxyyy"

Comment: that still doesn't explain why you can't concatenate the title. What is the higher level problem?

Comment: Do you mean:  var sss=$(this).dialog('option', 'title');
              $(this).dialog('option', 'title',sss+'yyy');

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. 
The very simplest is to run your line `$(".ui-dialog-title").before("xxx");` *AFTER* each call to opening a dialog. You cannot merely run it once and expect it to re-run on later dialog calls.

Another way to do this is to modify the jquery code. But I HIGHLY disrecommend doing that.

If I were to really want to systematically apply a prefix, I would make a helper function or wrapper that do this for me and call it instead of the jquery dialog directly.

Here is an example of what you might do and I have included a jsfiddle link as well (http://jsfiddle.net/stdw6j5q/1/):

HTML:

```
<div id="idDiv_MyDialog">Hi 1!</div>
<div id="idDiv_MyDialog2">Hi 2!</div>
<div id="idDiv_MyDialog3">Hi 3!</div>
<div id="idDiv_MyDialog4">Hi 4!</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
jDialog = function(options) {
  // THE WRAPPER TAKES TWO EXTRA OPTIONS TO IDENTIFY THE DIALOG AND THE TITLE PREFIX TO USE
  // I SET A DEFAULT SELECTOR IF NOTHING IS PASSED IN
  var _dialog = options && options.dialog ? options.dialog : '#idDiv_MyDialog'; 
  // HERE YOU CAN SET A DEFAULT PREFIX
  var _titlePrefix = options && options.titlePrefix ? options.titlePrefix : 'XYZ: '; 
  // UPDATE THE TITLE OPTION
  options.title = _titlePrefix + options.title; 
  // PASS THROUGH ALL YOUR NORMAL OPTIONS TO THE DIALOG
  $(_dialog).dialog(options); 
  // THIS RETURNS A HANDLE/REFERENCE TO THE DIALOG CREATED
  return $(_dialog); 
}

$(function() {

  // CALL YOUR WRAPPER WHEN YOU NEED TO CREATE/MOD THE DIALOG
  $myDialog1 = jDialog({
      title: 'Hey Jude', 
      close: function(event, ui) { $myDialog2.dialog('open'); } 
    });
  $myDialog2 = jDialog({
      dialog: '#idDiv_MyDialog2',  
      title: 'Don\'t let me down', 
      autoOpen: false, 
      close: function(event, ui) { $myDialog3.dialog('open'); }
    });
  $myDialog3 = jDialog({
      dialog: '#idDiv_MyDialog3',  
      title: 'Take a sad song', 
      autoOpen: false, 
      close: function(event, ui) { $myDialog4dialog('open'); } 
    });
  $myDialog4 = jDialog({
      dialog: '#idDiv_MyDialog4',  
      title: 'And make it better', 
      autoOpen: false 
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but task is to have line: $("#any_dialog_id").dialog("option", "title", "yyy") in the code and writing that line it has to be outcome "xxxyyy".

Comment: As I stated, you would need to run your `before` line after editing EVERY `dialog` call. OR you can modify the CORE LIBRARY of jQuery (the dialog plugin) which is an incredibly bad idea....unless you add this as an additional feature to jquery plugin open source group, which I am sure would not be taken seriously.

Comment: You might prefer @Scimonster solution. For simplicity, it is definitely simple. But a wrapper would let you also have a choice of being able to NOT include a prefix or a DIFFERENT prefix if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event to run whenever a dialog is created that adds the title.

```
$(document).on('dialogcreate', function(){ // let it bubble up
   $(".ui-dialog-title", this).before("xxx"); // add "xxx" before the title of this dialog
});
```

Comment: Yeah, you could do this on every page so any dialogue created would then fire this post event.... not a bad solution.